# How should I deal with the prompt to choose network authentification certificate in Windows 10 Security center?

Tags: windows-10, browser, certificate

I am a windows 10 user.

Every time I start my browser(edge DEV), the following dialogue box pops up. Sorry that it is Chinese. Let me translate it. On the top reads "windows security center". The title is "Choosing identity authentication certificate". What follows is the server(edge.activity...), the one who awarded this certificate (Adobe), and dates.

I clicked on "More option", and windows gives me a choice of 3 certificates at the end, as you can see.

Windows update does not resolve the issue. If you click on "property" of the certificate, you can see the words "windows does not have enough information to verify this certificate".

I do not dare to click "yes" as the bottom. **Can anyone tell me what it is?**. what should I do about it?
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that site you are connecting to wants ssl client verification?

Comment: @Aroly7 It's not the site I want to connect to. It seems to be what the edge browser want to connect to (edge.activity.windows.com). It could be requiring client verification since it is related to the microsoft account.

Comment: This is the Insider Preview of Edge, a pre-release product. It is not a polished product and you should probably look on the Insider forums for others with similar questions, or to report this.